# Development of Logic: Intuitive use vs what took so long to formalize?

Tags: lo.logic

As I am reading Frege and Boole,  I am struck by that there doesn't seem to be a great alternative to Aristotle's Logic until that time, and the development by Boole and Frege are correctly hailed as a revolution in the development the subject.

However, mathematicians have clearly been using first-order (& propositional) logic correctly in their proofs well before then, and indeed, humans - including small children! use simple forms of first order logic, and writers when constructing arguments for their books of political philosophy or whatever also employ non-Aristotelian logic freely.

So what took so long for Frege and Boole / humans to overthrow old syllogistic logic? "It's obvious in hindsight"'s not the answer I am looking for (see above).

Comment: You could start with [Wilfrid Hodges's website](http://wilfridhodges.co.uk/) and then invite him to join MO to give an answer.

Comment: Bertrand Russell wrote (in *Principles of Mathematics*, I think): "Mathematics and logic, historically speaking, have been entirely distinct studies. Mathematics has been connected with science, logic with Greek."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems more appropriate for [HSM](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I've now also posted it in HSM, I wasn't aware of its existence!

Comment: One thing to note is that actually there are many *unintuitive* aspects of modern logic. For example, it is very natural to think that universal claims have existential import, and that was central to ancient logic. In my experience, that kind of intuition is natural and needs to be *un*learned in order to understand modern logic.

Comment: Thank you @PaulTaylor for introducing me to to Wilfrid Hodges's website. What a wonderful resource!